# fprintf statement not executing properly in code blocks

Tags: c, printf

I tried running this program in code::blocks to display a list of names,but execution stops at fprintf.Ive tried one other program(given below) with fprintf and it seemed to work properly

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   FILE *ptr;
   ptr=fopen("D:\\test.txt","w+");
   char a[5];
   char i='a',j='a',k='a',l='a';
   a[0]='l';
   a[1]='a';
   for(i='a';i<=121;i++)
   {
      a[2]=i;
      for(j='a';j<=121;j++)
      {
        a[3]=j;
        switch(j)
           case 'a':
           case 'e':
           case 'i':
           case 'o':
           case 'u': 
             for(k='a';k<=121;k++)
             {
               a[4]=k;
               for(l='a';l<=117;l++)
               {
                  switch(l)
                     case 'a':
                     case 'e':
                     case 'i':
                     case 'o':
                     case 'u':{a[5]=l;fprintf(ptr,"%s",a);}
               }
             }
      }
   }
   fclose(ptr);
   return 0;
}
```

This is the program that works perfectly

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
    char a[50],b[50];
    printf("Enter a name\n");
    gets(b);
    FILE *ptr;
    ptr=fopen("D:\\test.txt","w+");
    fprintf(ptr,"%s",b);
    rewind(ptr);
    fscanf(ptr,"%s",&a);
    printf("%s",a);
    fclose(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Execution stops might mean anything.  You should check that the `fopen()` works before using the result.  You should also ensure that your strings are null terminated before printing them with `%s`, or make sure you limit the length printed to the length which is valid.  You probably want newlines somewhere in the output, too.  Also, don't use `gets()` ever.  Not even in demo code.  It is a bad habit to get into.  It is no longer a part of standard C.  You should probably use `'z'` instead of 121, and `'u'` in place of 117.

Comment: Hmmm; you also declare `char a[5];`, which means that you can only reference `a[0]` through `a[4]`.  Your code tries to write to `a[5]`, which is out of bounds (bad).  The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24430280/15168) by [noelkd](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1663352/noelkd) quietly changes the definition to `char a[7];`, but it should be shouted out as it is a crucial change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tidied up your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

      FILE *ptr = NULL;
      char a[7];

      /* Attempt to open the output file, and exit if something goes wrong. */
      ptr = fopen("D:\\test.txt", "w+");
      if (!ptr) { return 1; }  

      /* End the string with a NUL-terminator byte. */
      a[0] = 'l';
      a[1] = 'a';
      a[6] = 0;

      for (a[2] = 'a'; a[2] <= 121; a[2]++) {
            for (a[3] = 'a'; a[3] <= 121; a[3]++) {
                  switch (a[3]) {
                        case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
                              for (a[4] = 'a'; a[4] <= 121; a[4]++) {
                                    for (a[5] = 'a'; a[5] <= 117; a[5]++) {
                                          switch (a[5]) {
                                                case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
                                                      fprintf(ptr, "%s\n", a);
                                                break;
                                          }
                                    }
                              }
                        break;
                  }
            }
      }

      fclose(ptr);
      return 0;

}
```

I think that the problem is that the string `a` didn't include a zero-terminator byte, so I've added one. You should also ensure that the file is opened successfully before trying to write to it, so I have added that also. Comments have been left in the code at the relevant parts.

I've verified this is all working with [this](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php).

Comment: Thank you,the code works flawlessly.Im relatively new to programming,but isnt a string supposed to end with \0

Comment: Have a look at the line `a[6] = 0` this is setting the last element of the array as `0`, also note that if you say `char a[7]` its indexed from `0-6` i.e. you cannot use `a[7]` without corrupting memory. If the answer has helped please [consider accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: I'm not convinced by the reformatting (but it is good to add the `break` statements), but I am convinced about the 'not null terminated in the original'.

Comment: I've added a Community Wiki answer with my preferred formatting in it.  I don't need any credit for it, but I can't possibly format the code in a comment and would not be comfortable making such a major change to your answer.

Comment: Nice answer, but I did not ask  "how would [Jonathan Leffler] format the code"

Comment: Oh...sorry; are there two Noelkd's around?  The comment '@JonathanLeffler would you mind having a go at reformatting?' appears to come from you and appears to be addressed to me and appears to ask for me to provide a reformatted version of the code.  I must have misunderstood something.

Answer (score 1):

I have indented your code in your own post.
You have to properly indent your code, to avoid that the program be a mess.

After indentation, I saw that you are using `switch()` badly.
In practice, curly brackets should always be used with switch, even when not strictly necessary. Here you have a good model to take in account:

```
 switch(expression)
 {
    case 1:
      sentences...
      break;
    case 2:
      sentences...
      break;
    default:
      sentences...
      break;
 }
```

The excess of nested loops and switch sentences make difficult to follow the logic of the program.

Comment: Actually, even though it is _very_ aconventional, the original brace-less `switch` was valid C.  If you said _in practice, curly brackets should always be used with `switch`, even when not strictly necessary_, then I'd be in complete agreement with you.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: My intention was to said that. Finally, I made the changeg you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

In response to [Noelkd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1663352/noelkd)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429344/fprintf-statement-not-executing-properly-in-code-blocks/24430280?noredirect=1#comment37815843_24430280) asking "@JonathanLeffler would you mind having a go at reformatting?", this would be more or less the way I'd format it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char file[] = "D:\\test.txt"; 
    FILE *ptr = fopen(file, "w+");
    char a[7] = "la";
    if (ptr == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for writing\n", file);
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++)
    {
        a[2] = i;
        for (int j = 'a'; j <= 'z'; j++)
        {
            a[3] = j;
            switch (j)
            {
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
                for (int k = 'a'; k <= 'z'; k++)
                {
                    a[4] = k;
                    for (int l = 'a'; l <= 'u'; l++)
                    {
                        switch (l)
                        {
                        case 'a':
                        case 'e':
                        case 'i':
                        case 'o':
                        case 'u':
                            a[5] = l;
                            fprintf(ptr, "%s\n", a);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Main differences:

1. Use named string for file name, so I can report the file name in the error message if necessary.
2. Report error if cannot open file.
3. Initialize `ptr`, rather than assign later.
4. Resize `a`.
5. Initialize `a`.
6. Use C99/C++ declarations in `for` loops to avoid declaring `i`, `j`, `k`, `l` at the top.  If forced to use C89, then I'd not include the initializers since the variables are set when used.
7. The action for each `switch` is enclosed in braces.
8. Each case in each `switch` ends with `break` (even when technically unnecessary; it makes future changes more reliable).
9. Add a newline to the printing operation.
10. Remove the now redundant braces around the action.

I strongly prefer the [Allman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style) of brace layout, but recognize there are equally strong views in favour of the alternatives.  The brace layout was not one of the reasons I dislike noelkd's reformatting.

I've also used an indent of four spaces.  For a long time, I used tabs with tabstops set at 4, but I've switched to no tabs in the last decade or so.  I use the explicit `int main(void)` when the program ignores any arguments.  I compile using:

```
$ gcc -g -O3 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>      -Werror  fp2.c -o fp2
```

(or I use `-std=c11`).  I sometimes use extra options like `-Wshadow` or `-Wold-style-declaration` or `-Wold-style-definition`.

When I run the code, I get 16,900 lines of output:

```
laaaaa
laaaae
laaaai
laaaao
laaaau
…
lazuza
lazuze
lazuzi
lazuzo
lazuzu
```